# How to inject variables from azure application settings to spring @ConfigurationProperties annotated class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure-functions

I am developing an azure function written in java and using spring through spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure library. At the moment I am just testing the app locally with Azure functions core tools. I want to load some variables from the local.settings.json file to a configuration class that has @ConfigurationProperties annotation and constructor with @ConstructorBinding annotation.

The problem is that when I try to run this app it fails to instantiate the MyConfiguration class because it cannot find the properties file.

Is it possible to pass application settings from azure to Spring ConfigurationProperties class?

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    ...
    "VARIABLE1": "my_value"
  }
}
```

I created application.properties file in src/main/resources:

```
pref.variable1=${VARIABLE1}
```

I want to load pref.variable1 to this class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "pref")
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class MyConfiguration {
  public final String variable1;

  @ConstructorBinding
  public MyConfiguration(String variable1) {
    this.variable1 = variable1;
  }
}
```

My main class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.ëxample.configuration")
public class Main {
  /**
   * Spring boot entry point.
   *
   * @param args command-line arguments.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(...)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For running locally, set the Spring active profile to local as usual:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

For running the deployed environment:

Within the Azure portal: 
--> navigate to the function app 
--> select Configuration from the navigation pane 
--> select the Application settings tab

And add properties as needed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you explain what exactly setting `-Dspring.profiles.active=local` does? I don't have much experience with spring and I am not sure where should I add that argument, when I run `mvn package` or when I run the app with azure-functions-maven-plugin?

Comment: See the [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/environment.html#beans-definition-profiles), and [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) always has awesome guides.  That -D is when running locally.